# Uninitialized constant Sprockets::Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i get this error when i try to precompile my asset with the commande 
'rake assets:precompile'
I start getting this error when i have  install the gem 'turbo-sprockets-rails'
I using rails 4.0.0 and ruby 2.2.3.
can someone help me please.

I have Gem Uglifier -v 2.7.2

my Gemfile :

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
#gem 'minitest', '5.8.3'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.20'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'rack',"~> 1.5.5"
#upload images
gem 'paperclip',"~> 4.2"
#gem 'aws-sdk-v1'
#gem 'carrierware'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'sass', '3.2.19'
#gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
#gem 'materialize-sass', '0.97.3'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'turbo-sprockets-rails3'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '2.0.1'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
#gestion de privilège :
gem 'declarative_authorization','0.5.7'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'json', '1.8.3'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'
# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: evelopment

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [evelopment, :test]
```

when I remove the gem turbo-sprockets-rails in my Gemfile the command works well but in my views  my css and javascript are not walking

Comment: do you have  `Gem uglifier`  install ? Update your question with Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 fixed the asset pipeline issue that turbo-sprockets-rails was solving. You should just be able to delete that out of your asset pipeline and everything work fine when precompiling your assets.

Comment: thank you I have resolved my problem. I working on Windows os. I just pre-compile the application on a linux distribution (linux mint 17) and it run. but I do not know why because I have nothing added another gem